# Selecting rows in package `gt` using expressions

Tags: r, gt

The reference for [`fmt_number()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/fmt_number.html) says that one may select rows using an expression:

> **rows**
>
> Optional rows to format. Providing either `everything()` (the default) or `TRUE` results in all rows in columns being formatted. Can either be a vector of row captions provided in `c()`, a vector of row indices, or a helper function focused on selections. The select helper functions are: `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, `contains()`, `matches()`, `one_of()`, `num_range()`, and `everything()`. **We can also use expressions to filter down to the rows we need (e.g., `[colname_1] > 100 & [colname_2] < 50`)**.

However, I haven't find out how to make this work. I tried the following (this is just an illustration; these number transformations do not make sense in this data set):

```r
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

df = starwars

gt_tb = gt(df) %>%
    fmt_number(
        rows = [birth_year] > 20,
        pattern = '({x})'
    )

gt_tb = gt(df) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = mass,
    rows = [birth_year] > 20,
    pattern = '({x})'
  )

gt_tb = gt(df) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = mass,
    rows = expression([birth_year] > 20),
    pattern = '({x})'
  )

gt_tb = gt(df) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = mass,
    rows = df[birth_year] > 20,
    pattern = '({x})'
  )

gt_tb = gt(df) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = mass,
    rows = everything([birth_year] > 20),
    pattern = '({x})'
  )
```

Also tried their quoted equivalent.

Pretty new to this package, sorry if I missed something evident!

Comment: You're so close! After choosing the column (like `mass` as you did) you can pick specific rows using code like `rows = birth_year > 20`. You gotta get rid of the square brackets. I can see why the documentation was confusing on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to specify `columns`:

```
df %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_number(
    columns = where(is.numeric),
    rows = birth_year > 20,
    pattern = '({x})'
  )
```

This gives us (as a screenshot/sample):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I got bogged down with the `[...]` format.

Answer (score 1):

> We can also use expressions to filter down to the rows we need (e.g., [colname_1] > 100 & [colname_2] < 50).

The example uses the brackets (`[]`) to tell you that those are placeholders, it's not a valid syntax.

In your case it would be

```
    fmt_number(
        columns = mass,
        rows = birth_year > 20,
        pattern = '({x})'
    )
```

Comment: This example doesn't work because you haven't specified a `columns` arg.

Comment: Oops, fixed thanks, I took the first example